# how to load meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0; URL="somedomain" into a div.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to make a ajax request to a page which contains below meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0; URL=https://www.ohterDomain.com/help?nodeId=2&view=content-only">
```

Upon successful ajax call I am not getting the correct content in my response object. And the meta tag causing my entire page to reload with the given URL.

The URL in mata tag is from different domain and throwing cross domain exception on separate ajax call.

Is there any way to load the refreshed meta URL into my response object? Or any other workaround to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

AJAX(as approach) also known as XMLHttpRequest or XHR is typical way to load data without reloading page.

But you are going to request different domain. So you will porobably face CORS restrictions.

Is it acceptable for you to load data into `<iframe>` instead of `<div>`?

Comment: The URL which I am using to make ajax call is from same domain, but it contains meta tag  with different domain. I case of iframe I am getting 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Answer (score 0):

How is the AJAX call triggered? Make sure to cancel the original event when clicking a link or submitting a form.